# Send token from addressA to addressB through contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

im tryin to do a function inside my contract that when someone use it:

1. it get the tokenX_v1 balance of msg.sender,
2. send the same amount of tokenX_v2 from my contract,
3. send his tokenX_v1 to my contract or burn address.

part 1 and 2 i did it like this:

```
function query_oldBalance(address _adrs) view public returns (uint) {
  address _tokenAddress = "tokenV1"
  return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(_adrs);

function myfunction() public {
  _tokenTransfer(address(this),msg.sender,query_oldBalance(msg.sender) , false);
```

and until here it works as intended but now i need to remove tokenV1 from the msg.sender, and i thought to do a transfer to send it to the contract or the burn address, but when i try to do a transferFrom i get:
`execution reverted: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance` even if i put the allowance to a much bigger number of what im trying to transfer
if i try with a normal transfer i got `"execution reverted: Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.` same here i tried to set the maxtxamount to a much bigger number than the token im trying to transfer.. about the allowance,
im not sure about how allowance and approve works and if i need it in this case but this is what i tried:

```
IERC20(_tokenAddress).allowance(msg.sender, address(this)); 
IERC20(_tokenAddress).approve(address(this),query_oldBalance(msg.sender)); //tried with this multiplied by 10 same story
```

i really don't understand how to do this addressA to addressB token transfer through contract.. Hope someone can help me Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        IERC20(_tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), old_balance);
```

and before call this func the user should approve the address of the new token ON the old token contract